# jar created on windows doesn't work on linux

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, intellij-idea, executable-jar

I exported a runnable jar from Eclipse on windows 8.1. When I try t tun it on kali linux it gives 'Invalid or corrupt jarfile'

I then created the jar using intellij, but it give the same error on kali linux.

Jar works fine on my windows system created by either method. I am using oracle jdk 6 to export the jar. On kali linux I have openjdk installed.

Oupout of `unzip DocUploder.jar` on kali linux

```
Archive:  DocUploder.jar
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
note:  DocUploder.jar may be a plain executable, not an archive
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of DocUploder.jar or
        DocUploder.jar.zip, and cannot find DocUploder.jar.ZIP, period.
```

Comment: How do you run the jar on linux?

Comment: Some version of Java (I know stupid question)

Comment: Try to run `jar vft yourjar.jar` or `unzip yourjar.jar`. It is just to check whether the jar indeed corrupted.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, OP says that the jar is corrupted, not class file. It probably means that the java version is less relevant.

Comment: BTW, IMHO, do not use OpenJDK. Use JDK from Oracle instead.

Comment: If you cannot unzip the file it is indeed corrupted. How do you copy the file from windows to linux?

Comment: I copied using drag n drop of virtual box. Will try other methods. Thanks

Comment: use ftp and ensure that it is in binary mode.

Comment: Try to copy the file back. I believe that it will be corrupted on windows too. Check the file size on both machines. If size is the same find a way to calculate hash code. Anyway, you problem seems to be in copying.

Comment: Thanks all. I copied using pendrive and it works.

Comment: @AlexR if you can answer it, I will accept. It might help others later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since the answer is obvious after the long chat I'd provide the action list that helps to find problem like "my jar does not run".

1. Check the command line. Be sure the classpath is correct.
2. Check the error message. If it complains that jar is corrupted, check jar. If it complains about the class version check JRE version. If it throws `ClassNotFoundException` or `ClassDefNotFoundError` check classpath. If it throws `NoSuchMethodException` or similar check compatibility of your libraries.
3. To check jar file try `jar vft your.jar` (if you have JDK) or commands like `unzip` on linux or extract zip file on windows. If this does not work - jar file is corrupted.
4. If jar file runs on one machine and does not run on other check how did you copy the file. First check the file size on both machines. Use `ls -l` on unix or `dir` on windows. If files have the same size try to compare them by creating hash. Use `md5sum my.jar` on linux and tool like `WinMd5` on windows. Other possibility is to copy file forward and back and check that it is still ok.